# Why effects flow during camera movement in After Effects 2020?

Tags: after-effects, effects

I have a few vector layers that are parent to Null Object. If I apply Rough Edges or Turbulant Displace to any of these layers, and then animate the scale on my Null, my layers begin to move/flow/leak.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?
I want them to remain static after applying the effects.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the Roughen Edges effect is a pixel-based effect applied to the entire display of your comp.  If you pre-comp the effect first, it won't display the animating edges.

Or you could try applying this expression to the Roughen Edges offset (transform) property, as explained [here](https://creativecow.net/forums/thread/roughen-edges-alternative-effectae/):

```
parent.position * 400 / effect(“Roughen Edges”)(“Scale”)
```

Comment: I am working with vector graphics on a current project. If I pre-comp the effect first, it won't display the animating edges but my layer will no longer be in the vector. In the case of expression, the result is the same. As a result, I need vector graphics, which I can enlarge by 1000% without loss of quality. Is it really impossible to do this in After Effects?